# CSS Grid after applying the row gutter(row-gap) grid container height is less than grid itself

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have made a simple Grid container:

```css
.grid-container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    row-gap: 6%;
 }
 
 .grid-item {
   background: #4F5C40;
   border: 1px solid black;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
 }
 
 .grid-neighbour {
   background: #404F5C;
   height: 150px;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
   <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid-neighbour"></div>
```

The problem is after I apply `row-gap: 6%`, my .grid-container height becomes less than the grid itself. Due to this, the next element `.grid-neightbour` occupies some of the space of the last row of the grid resulting in hiding some of the content.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you provide more code like the whole css and html?

Comment: please add enough code so it reproduce your issue, empty div have an height of 0 .... only the gaps could grow the grid as the code you share shows

Comment: Thank you @BSMP for editing the question and completing the missing part.

Comment: Yes, it answers @benvc. Thank you.